# Index not being used in the Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an Oracle query that can be represented as below.

```
 SELECT * FROM
 TABLE A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON
 A.FACT_KEY=B.FACT_KEY AND
 A.ENTITY_ID=B.ENTITY_ID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON
 A.FACT_KEY=C.FACT_KEY AND
 A.ENTITY_ID=C.ENTITY_ID AND
 C.CREATED_DT BETWEEN 201611 AND 201712
 LEFT OUTER JOIN D ON
 A.FACT_KEY=D.FACT_KEY AND
 A.ENTITY_ID=D.ENTITY_ID
```

The table volumes are :  Table A = 60 million, Table B = 170 million,
Table C = 150 million and  Table D = 200 million

I have a normal indexes on the columns `(Fact_key,Entity_id)` for tables
B,C and D. I also have a normal index on the `created_dt` column of
table C

When I explained the plan of the query I could see tables B and D are
going for a full table scan and Table C is going for *Table Access By
Rowid* and *Index Range Scan*.

Is there any way I could enforce index scans for Table B and D

Comment: If Oracle decides that it has to read a significant portion of the rows in the table, the optimizer may decide that a full table scan is more efficient than an index.

Comment: `When I explained the plan of the query` - please append this plan to the question.

Comment: Your query returns *all* 60 million rows from A, along with all matching rows from tables B and D.  How many of the 170M rows in B match?  How many of the 200M rows in D?  I'm guessing most if not all. Using an index is would only make sense (possibly) if the matching fraction of the rows in B and D was low.  Using an index is not always better than a full table scan.